# Raw pointer from a Box using '& mut *' behaviour is not understandable

Tags: pointers, rust, raw

I was creating linked list using raw pointers / unsafe Rust purely for learning purpose. I noticed something which I can't understand.

```
struct Node{
    data : i32,
    next : * mut Node,
}

struct MyFirstUnsafeQueue{
    head : * mut Node,
    tail : * mut Node,
}
impl MyFirstUnsafeQueue{
    fn new()->Self{
        return MyFirstUnsafeQueue { head: std::ptr::null_mut(), tail: std::ptr::null_mut() };
    }
    /**
     * Adds an element at the rear of the queue
     */
    fn push_1(& mut self, element:i32){
        let mut new_node = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Node{
            data :element,
            next : std::ptr::null_mut(),
        }));
        if self.head.is_null(){
            //https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#common-ways-to-create-raw-pointers 
            self.head = new_node;
            self.tail = new_node;
        }else{
            unsafe{
                (*self.tail).next = new_node;
                self.tail = new_node;
            }
        }
    }

    fn push_2(& mut self, element:i32){
        let mut new_node = Box::new(Node{
            data :element,
            next : std::ptr::null_mut(),
        });
        if self.head.is_null(){
            //https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#common-ways-to-create-raw-pointers 
            self.head = & mut * new_node;
            self.tail = & mut * new_node;
        }else{
            unsafe{
                (*self.tail).next = & mut *new_node;
                self.tail = & mut * new_node;
            }
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_push_1(){
    unsafe{
        let mut q:MyFirstUnsafeQueue = MyFirstUnsafeQueue::new();
        q.push_1(1);
        assert_eq!(1, (*q.head).data);
        assert_eq!(1, (*q.tail).data);
        q.push_1(2);
        assert_eq!(1, (*q.head).data);
        assert_eq!(2, (*q.tail).data);
   }
}

#[test]
fn test_push_2(){
    unsafe{
        let mut q:MyFirstUnsafeQueue = MyFirstUnsafeQueue::new();
        q.push_2(1);
        assert_eq!(1, (*q.head).data);
        assert_eq!(1, (*q.tail).data);
        q.push_2(2);
        assert_eq!(1, (*q.head).data);
        assert_eq!(2, (*q.tail).data);
   }
}
```

test_push_2 fails with below error message. But, when I debug it, it passes.

```
thread 'hello_unsafe::unsafe_queue_02::test_push_2' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `1`,
 right: `2`', src/hello_unsafe/unsafe_queue_02.rs:74:9
```

I am using visual studio code + Mac OS. And no problem with test_push_1. I am unable figure out why is it happening.

Comment: Your question title does not match your question body. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test using `push_2` exhibits undefined behavior, use-after-free, because `new_node` is destroyed at the end of each call, which will deallocate the contents. The `head` and `tail` pointers are dangling when you call `.push_2()` again.

Your test with `push_1` works because `Box::into_raw` converts the `Box` into a raw pointer and doesn't deallocate it.